# Reading RFID tag in android App using NFC Reader

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, nfc, rfid

I am new to this Android Development

I have to develop an application for my final year projet ! An app which will **read RFID tag using NFC/rfid reader**.

So my question is how can I develop an app to read NFC/RFID tag data in android App using NFC/RFID Reader hardware.how do I program to connect that reader from my application and use that data to searh in a particular website to show results.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify if you mean to use the built in NFC hardware in some phone or via a external USB reader?

Comment: hi @Andrew, do you know a module that I can use for external USB reader? I use `react-native-nfc-manager` for my project that use internal reader.

Comment: @Andrew can you please read this ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71893604/is-there-anyway-we-could-use-the-data-from-rfid-to-fetch-something-from-another